# Facebook not showing full url

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to get the Facebook like to work. It kind of works but it gives the wrong title. While I was messing around with the Facebook like button, I noticed that it didn't complete the url so it would give me

> www.mysite.com/product#

instead of

> www.mysite.com/product#item1

if I go to

> https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

and I enter the correct url it shows up in the debugger, but it doesn't seem to work on my site.

Here is the Facebook code

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://mysite/product#item1"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

That´s just an anchor on a Page, Facebook does not read that one. Meaning, it will not be a separate URL for Facebook. If you want different Metatags with the same Link, you have to use GET parameters instead.